# How can I turn off android in-call echo cancellation?

Tags: android, echo-cancellation

I know there are somewhat related questions in this field...

Still: Is there a way to disable echo cancellation while in android voice call?

Comment: Why on earth people unvote without thinking?! There is legitimate reason for this question...

Answer (score 0):

On a regular voice call you can not do any change to the audio path. But, if you are using a VoIP client on your side then (e.g. skype-out), the usage/configuration of different audio processing algorithm might be configurable in the VoIP application itself. You need to try few VoIP application to find out.

Comment: Yepp VoIP is indeed "do what ever you want"///